# Spark AR login failed

Tags: facebook, authentication, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to install and login Spark AR with my existing fb account, but it keep saying my password is wrong ( of course I assure it is correct )

My mac OS is Catalina 10.15.4, and the Spark AR downloaded is the latest version. Does anyone know if it is compatible? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to your facebook account via any browser go to Settings->Account Security and ***Turn On Two-factor authentication***.

Then login again in Spark AR Studio, this will ask for verification as you set up in 2FA and you will be logged in to Spark AR Studio.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable two-factor authentication for your Facebook account.

Comment: I already have 2 factor auth setup and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

i am gonna answer my own question as its fixed right now. I just logged out and logged in facebook again, then it works.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? Do you have two-factor authentication enabled like others suggested? Also, remember mark this post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

just create an new account Facebook and login with account you have already created, then it works

Answer (score 0):

Open your Facebook account in your mobile browser. Keeping your account active on Mobile browser now try logging in SPARK AR. It worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I've keep getting notice of "unrecognized device" from FB and "saving browser" won't fix the problem..